com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalTime` from String "7:45PM"
I upgraded my java project to jdk17, spring 6.1 and springboot 3.3
I am getting
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalTime` from String "7:45PM": Failed to deserialize java.time.LocalTime: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '7:45PM' could not be parsed at index 4

error while fixing my junits
Reproducible code -
     public static ObjectMapper getObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_IGNORED_PROPERTIES, false);
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_NULL_CREATOR_PROPERTIES, false);
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.ORDER_MAP_ENTRIES_BY_KEYS, true);
        return objectMapper;
    }
    
    public static <T> T getJsonFixtureFromString(String jsonString, Class<T> clazz) {
        return getObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, clazz);
    }
    
    @Test
    public void myTest(){
        String s = "{\"name\":\"Evening Restriction\",\"restrictions\":[{\"starttime\":\"7:45PM\",\"endtime\":\"8:15PM\"}]}"
        
        RestrictProfileDTO dto = getJsonFixtureFromString(s, RestrictProfileDTO.class);
    }

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class RestrictProfileDTO {
    @JsonProperty(value = "name")
    private String name;
    
    @JsonProperty(value = "restrictions")
    private List<RestrictionDTO> restrictions;
    
}

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class RestrictionDTO {
    @JsonProperty(value = "starttime")
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "h:mma")
    private LocalTime startTime;
    
    @JsonProperty(value = "endtime")
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "h:mma")
    private LocalTime endTime;
}

Complete logs -
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create class RestrictProfileDTO from json {"name":"Evening Restriction","restrictions":[{"restrict_day":"2","starttime":"7:45PM","endtime":"8:15PM"}]} .
    at TestUtils.getJsonFixtureFromString(TestUtils.java:79)
    at CallMenuRestrictionResourceTest.testCreateProfileBadRequestIllegalArgumentException(CallMenuRestrictionResourceTest.java:110)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:76)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:108)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:40)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:52)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy5.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$2.run(TestWorker.java:176)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:113)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:65)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalTime` from String "7:45PM": Failed to deserialize java.time.LocalTime: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '7:45PM' could not be parsed at index 4
 at [Source: REDACTED (`StreamReadFeature.INCLUDE_SOURCE_IN_LOCATION` disabled); line: 1, column: 130] (through reference chain: RestrictProfileDTO["restrictions"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->RestrictionDTO["starttime"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException.from(InvalidFormatException.java:67)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.weirdStringException(DeserializationContext.java:1958)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleWeirdStringValue(DeserializationContext.java:1245)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.JSR310DeserializerBase._handleDateTimeException(JSR310DeserializerBase.java:176)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.LocalTimeDeserializer._fromString(LocalTimeDeserializer.java:195)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.LocalTimeDeserializer.deserialize(LocalTimeDeserializer.java:109)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.LocalTimeDeserializer.deserialize(LocalTimeDeserializer.java:37)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:129)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:310)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:177)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer._deserializeFromArray(CollectionDeserializer.java:361)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:246)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:30)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:129)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:399)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:185)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:342)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4905)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3848)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3816)
    at TestUtils.getJsonFixtureFromString(TestUtils.java:77)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '7:45PM' could not be parsed at index 4
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2052)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1954)
    at java.base/java.time.LocalTime.parse(LocalTime.java:465)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.LocalTimeDeserializer._fromString(LocalTimeDeserializer.java:193)
    ... 68 more

I was using version 2.16.0 of com.fasterxml.jackson.core, I changed it to latest stable version 2.17.0 but still the error is not resolved. I was expecting that maybe higher version is compatible with jdk17. But error did not resolved.
The error resolved when I changed capital PM to small pm in string passed to getJsonFixtureFromString() method. But how to resolve this without changing string.
In jdk11 this error did not come.

Does not seem like version issue, but can you try with 2.17.2? I can't try now with other versions at the moment, but this one works for me.

@Chaosfire with 2.17.2 version also i am getting error - Cannot deserialize value of type java.time.LocalTime from String "7:45PM": Failed to deserialize java.time.LocalTime: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '7:45PM' could not be parsed at index 4

@Arjun Post details as edits to your Question, not as Comments.

The best solution is to not used localized text when serializing or exchanging date-time values textually. Use only standard ISO 8601 formats. For a time-of-day that would be 24-hour format with padding zeros, 19:45 rather than 7:45PM.

You can try creating a custom deserializer.
@JsonDeserialize(using = CaseInsensitiveLocalTimeDeserializer.class)
@JsonProperty(value = "starttime")
private LocalTime startTime;

@JsonDeserialize(using = CaseInsensitiveLocalTimeDeserializer.class)
@JsonProperty(value = "endtime")
private LocalTime endTime;

with :
public class CaseInsensitiveLocalTimeDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<LocalTime> {

    private final DateTimeFormatter formatter;

    public CaseInsensitiveLocalTimeDeserializer() {
        this.formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h:mma").withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
    }

    @Override
    public LocalTime deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        String timeStr = p.getText().toUpperCase();  // Convert to upper case to handle AM/PM consistently
        try {
            return LocalTime.parse(timeStr, formatter);
        } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
            throw new InvalidFormatException(p, "Failed to parse time", timeStr, LocalTime.class);
        }
    }
}

And the mapper would look like this when adding the deserializer.
public static ObjectMapper getObjectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JavaTimeModule javaTimeModule = new JavaTimeModule();
    javaTimeModule.addDeserializer(LocalTime.class, new CaseInsensitiveLocalTimeDeserializer());
    objectMapper.registerModule(javaTimeModule);
    // Other configurations...
    return objectMapper;
}

